# Solr UI Unexpected Query Results

Tags: apache, solr

I have been following [this tutorial](https://factorpad.com/tech/solr/tutorial/solr-schema.html) on how to use Solr. I have been trying to follow along closely but it seems I have missed something. When the tutorial searches films for Spike Lee they get a few results. If I type my query the same I get zero results. However if I use the default query string (*:*) it returns all 1100 results just as in the tutorial. In the tutorial they are using version 7 while I am on version 7.5 which could cause an issue.

EDIT:
The search does work properly BUT only when I define a field (directed_by:Spike Lee)

some search strings i have tried
q=:

- Spike Lee
- "Spike Lee"
- Spike+Lee
- Spike
- *:Spike

**SOLUTION: MESSED STEP IN TUTORIAL, MUST CREATE copyField AND RE-INDEX**

Comment: What is the field type for `directed_by`?

Comment: @MatsLindh it should be text. I used the default settings like in the tutorial. If theres a way to check, I can verify.

Comment: @FamousAv8er : check in the schema.xml or managed-schema file at path ...\solr-7.5.0\solr-7.5.0\server\solr\configsets

Comment: @MatsLindh in my managed schema its labeled as text_general

Comment: When you're using the query string "Spike Lee", are you using the edismax handler and the `qf` parameter, or are you just entering text as the query? In the latter case, the default search field (`df` will be used instead). If that isn't a field that has any content by default, no hits will be found. Solr will not search all fields for you.

Comment: @MatsLindh so after more digging, it seems to be because a copyField was not created with source="*" and dest="_text_"

Comment: Which is relevant because the default search field is `_text_` - you can use `qf` with dismax/edismax to tell Solr explicitly which fields (and how to weigh them) it should search. Using `_text_` won't really allow you to tweak relevance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The solution was to add a copyField with source="*" and dest="*text*"**

because of this however I will need to now re-index